# kobold2d disable full screen on orientation change

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit, kobold2d

I want to include cocos2d scene besides UIKit GUI elements in my app using kobold2d library, so it should take just part of the screen.

I alter cocos2d glview size like this when initializing the first layer:

```
UIView * glView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]view];
    CGRect rct = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 400);

    [glView setFrame:rct];
```

The view is displayed properly until I change orientation, then glview again becomes fullscreen. Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

XCode 4.5.2, iOS 6, Kobold2D 2.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling reshape after setting the frame might help:

```
UIView * glView = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]view];
CGRect rct = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 400);

[glView setFrame:rct];
[glView reshape];
```

Comment: .. and it wouldn't help even if it had, because CCDirector put as a window rootViewController tries to shrink it's view to the whole window anytime You change orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Now after some experiments I kind of found solution, please correct me if I am wrong. At least this worked for me, hope someone else makes use of it either.

CCDirectorIOS is a UIViewController, and it is usually being set as a `rootViewController` of app `window`.

Looks like `[window rootViewController]` is responsible for making it's `view` fullscreen every time orientation changes, thus forcing all children to layout (I knew that!!! %).

Therefore, to avoid glView shrinking to the whole window now and then, give window another UIViewController as a rootController, not the CCDirector. That another UIViewController should have it's own brand new UIView. This new rootView is what this rootViewController can resize however he wants, leave alone our glView. Now, assign director as a child of rootController and assign glView as a child of a rootView.

Set glView to size You want - and off we go! Now when rootView resizes, glView doesn't. In my case it still had to resize while maintaining free space proportions so i used setAutoresizingMask on it. please gurus tell what You think.

known caveats:

- rootController and navController of KKAppDelegate not used except for proper initial orientation
- this raises bar of least ios version to 5 because of addChildViewController: method

the code inside app's AppDelegate (suppose ARC is ON):

```
-(void) initializationComplete
{
#ifdef KK_PLATFORM_IOS

    RootViewController * rootvc = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
    UIView * rootView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    [rootvc setView:rootView];
    [rootvc.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];//to see views in colors
    [window setRootViewController:rootvc];

    [rootvc addChildViewController:[CCDirector sharedDirector]];

    UIView * glview = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]view];
    [rootvc.view addSubview:glview];//[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]];

    CGRect glRect = CGRectInset(rootvc.view.bounds, 50, 50);//our glview frame is smaller than rootView frame

    [glview setFrame:glRect];
    [glview setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];//so the view size follows window's size even though it's not fullscreen

#endif

}
```